# Merging a tag into a particular branch

Tags: git, git-tag

when I do `git tag` I see tags like `Aisis1.0` well id like to make a 1.0 branch, `git checkout -b dev1.0` and then merge in the tag called `Aisis1.0` is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, once you're on the new `dev1.0` branch, just type

```
git merge Aisis1.0
```